# Listagem baseada em consulta no banco

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Antes de mais nada, peço desculpas se a pergunta for vaga, já que é um tema bastante abrangente.

Hoje eu tenho um sistema de cadastro e consulta de alunos, onde a consulta é feita exclusivamente por CPF, já que é um identificador único e uma constraint no banco de dados me garantirá que não existirão CPF repetidos, assim retornando apenas um resultado na consulta.

A consulta no banco de dados é feita via dataSet, por uma classe auxiliadora que temos. O método é basicamente este:

```
CeltaWare.Data.SqlHelper.FillDataset(
                    sqlConn,
                    CommandType.Text,
                    "SELECT * FROM ALUNOS WHERE CPF = @CPF",
                    dataSet,
                    new string[] { "Alunos" },
                    new SqlParameter("@CPF", aluno.Cpf));
```

E se no caso, eu quiser passar a pesquisar pelo nome também?

Obviamente, podem existir diversos alunos com o primeiro nome igual, e então o aplicativo deve retornar uma lista para selecionarmos o aluno que queremos.

A questão é: Como essa lista deve ser criada? Por ser iniciante no C#, eu não tenho muita ideia de como fazer isso. Seria um novo Form, com labels que teriam o `Text` substituído pela nossa pesquisa?

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Você não informou qual é o seu *front end*, se *Forms* ou *Web*, mas como pode ser mais de um registro, uma tipo *grid* pode ajudar (*GridView* por exemplo)

Comment: Desculpe, é WindowsForms

Comment: Nesse caso você pode usar *DataGridView*, toda a documentação com exemplos você pode ver aqui: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/datagridview-control-overview-windows-forms

Comment: @LucasBustos o DataGridView seria a opoção ideal, mais se prefere usar uma `List<Aluno>`: Você tem criar uma lista da Classe Aluno, alimentando suas propriedades com um `foreach` percorrendo todas as colunas de cada linha do seu dataset. Posta a `Class Aluno` e o método inteiro usado no dataset para servir de base, que monto um esquema a partir do `dataset` que vc já tem.

Answer (score 1):

Em meu sistema, fazemos isso, com diferença na linguagem apenas.

- Realizamos a consulta sempre via nome.
  -- Tratamos para que caso o retorno da consulta seja superior a 1, apresente os dados em uma Tela ("Lista Pessoas")
  -- Aonde colocamos o Código, CPF e o Nome da Pessoa.
  --- Aí quando clica duas vezes na Pessoa, carrega os dados no cadastro.

-- A Tela, é composta por um List.

Não sei se ficou bem claro, mas segue o mesmo principio da solução que você imaginou.